# Different Invocations with one Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill `SkillIntent` that when you ask it a ask about a specific game, it replies with the description of that skill. Works perfectly - What I'm trying to get it do now, however, is to reply with WHO has that Skill, if asked differently.

Below is my working code:

```
'use strict';

var AlexaSkill = require('./AlexaSkill'),
    descriptions = require('./descriptions');

var APP_ID = undefined;

var ZombicideSkills = function () {
    AlexaSkill.call(this, APP_ID);
};

// Extend AlexaSkill
ZombicideSkills.prototype = Object.create(AlexaSkill.prototype);
ZombicideSkills.prototype.constructor = ZombicideSkills;

ZombicideSkills.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
    var speechText = "You can ask a question like, what does this skill do? ... Now, what can I help you with.";

    var repromptText = "For instructions on what you can say, please say help me.";
    response.ask(speechText, repromptText);
};

ZombicideSkills.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    "SkillIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var skillSlot = intent.slots.Skill,
            skillName;
        if (skillSlot && skillSlot.value){
            skillName = skillSlot.value.toLowerCase();
        }

        var cardTitle = "Description for " + skillName,
            description = descriptions[skillName],
            speechOutput,
            repromptOutput;
        if (description) {
            speechOutput = {
                speech: description,
                type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
            };
            response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, cardTitle, description);
        } else {
            var speech;
            if (skillName) {
                speech = "I'm sorry, I don't know if I know " + skillName + ". What else can I help with?";
            } else {
                speech = "I'm sorry, I currently do not know that skill. What else can I help with?";
            }
            speechOutput = {
                speech: speech,
                type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
            };
            repromptOutput = {
                speech: "What else can I help with?",
                type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
            };
            response.ask(speechOutput, repromptOutput);
        }
    },

    "AMAZON.StopIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    },

    "AMAZON.CancelIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    },

    "AMAZON.HelpIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechText = "You can ask questions such as, what does this skill do, or, you can say exit... Now, what can I help you with?";
        var repromptText = "You can say things like, what does this skill do, or you can say exit... Now, what can I help you with?";
        var speechOutput = {
            speech: speechText,
            type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
        };
        var repromptOutput = {
            speech: repromptText,
            type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
        };
        response.ask(speechOutput, repromptOutput);
    }
};

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var zombicide = new ZombicideSkills();
    zombicide.execute(event, context);
};
```

It's modeled very similarly to that of the MC Helper. Would I just implement an additional intentHandlers called 'ActorIntent' and then in the Utterences specify `ActorIntent what {actors} have the {skill} skill?`

I've been playing around with the idea, but I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot with Lambda functions yet - It's kind of just 'upload and see if the endpoint is reachable'.

It would be annoying if I had to have two -different- skills for this, but I'm unsure? Is it just an issue with my code base, and I should be able to go and create an `ActorIntent` without issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a different Intent, for example, `SkillOwnerIntent` and in the interaction model in the Alexa Developer Portal, define utterances for that intent. You definitely do not need to make another skill for this.

Comment: Appreciate it - I wasn't sure if my secondary Intent was breaking the function, or something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with good user experience would be the following:

1. A user aks about a game-skill which triggers your SkillIntent

   > In your code: Save this skill in a variable (e.g. as a string)
2. Alexa tells your skill's description and might ask for further questions.
3. The user can now ask: Which actors have this skill? This triggers your intent ActorIntent.

   > Utterances: ActorIntent Which actors have this skill?
4. You know which skill the user is talking about (because you stored it in a variable). Now alexa can tell the specific actors.

Intent schema example:

```
{
"intents": [
  {
    "intent": "ActorIntent"
  },
  {
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "skill",
        "type": "SKILL"
      }
    ],
    "intent": "SkillIntent"
  }
}
```